# How to create a many to many service in nestjs

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, nest

I'm confused because I have a user-auth.service.ts file that looks like this

**user-auth.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserAuthorizationService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Users)
    private readonly usersRepository: Repository<Users>,
    @InjectRepository(TcmEntity)
    private readonly entitiesRepository: Repository<TcmEntity>,
    @InjectRepository(Divisi)
    private readonly divisiRepository: Repository<Divisi>,
    @InjectRepository(Departemen)
    private readonly departmentsRepository: Repository<Departemen>,
    @InjectRepository(UsersEntity)
    private readonly userEintiysRepository: Repository<UsersEntity>,
  ) {}

  async findOne(condition): Promise<Users> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOne(condition);
  }

  async create(body): Promise<Users> {
    try {
      const entitys = await this.entitiesRepository.findBy({
        id: In(body.entity_id),
      });
      const divisis = await this.divisiRepository.findBy({
        id: In(body.divisi_id),
      });

      const departemen = await this.departmentsRepository.findBy({
        id: In(body.departemen_id),
      });

      const user = await this.usersRepository.findOneByOrFail({
        id: body.users_id,
      });

      user.entitys = entitys;
      user.divisis = divisis;
      user.departemens = departemen;

      return await this.usersRepository.save(user);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error instanceof EntityNotFoundError) {
        return null;
      }

      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

i want to call

```
@InjectRepository(Users Entity) private readonly userEintiys Repository: Repository<Users Entity>
```

because i want to make input createdBy so i have to call it

**users-entitys.entity.ts**

```
@Entity('tcm_users_entitys')
export class UsersEntity {
  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at', nullable: true })
  createdAt: Date;
  @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at', nullable: true, default: null })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @ManyToOne(() => Users, (user) => user.id, {
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'created_by',
  })
  createdBy: Users;

  @ManyToOne(() => Users, (user) => user.id, {
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'updated_by',
  })
  updatedBy: Users;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @PrimaryColumn()
  users_id: number;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @PrimaryColumn()
  entity_id: number;
}
```

**users.entity.ts**

```
@Entity('tcm_user')
export class Users {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ name: 'nama', length: 100 })
  nama: string;

  @Column({ name: 'no_telp', length: 50 })
  noTelp: string;

  @Column({ name: 'email', length: 100 })
  email: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role, (role) => role.id, {
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'role',
  })
  role: Role;

  @Column({ name: 'password', length: 100 })
  password: string;

  @Column({ name: 'is_aktif', default: true })
  isAktif: boolean;

  @Column({ name: 'created_by', nullable: true })
  createdBy: string;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at', nullable: true })
  createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ name: 'updated_by', nullable: true })
  updatedBy: string;

  @UpdateDateColumn({
    name: 'updated_at',
    nullable: true,
    default: null,
    onUpdate: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)',
  })
  updatedAt: Date;

  @ManyToMany(() => TcmEntity, (entitys) => entitys.users)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'tcm_users_entitys',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'users_id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'entity_id',
    },
  })
  entitys?: TcmEntity[];
```

**entity.entity.ts**

```
@Entity('tcm_entity')
export class TcmEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column({ name: 'code' })
  code: string;

  @Column({ name: 'name' })
  name: string;

  @Column({ name: 'description', nullable: true })
  desc: string;

  @Column({ name: 'is_active', default: false })
  isActive: boolean;

  // @Column({ name: 'created_by', nullable: true })
  // createdBy: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => Users, (user) => user.id, {
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'created_by',
  })
  createdBy: Users;

  @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'created_at', nullable: true })
  createdAt: Date;

  // @Column({ name: 'updated_by', nullable: true })
  // updatedBy: string;
  @ManyToOne(() => Users, (user) => user.id, {
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({
    name: 'updated_by',
  })
  updatedBy: Users;

  @UpdateDateColumn({ name: 'updated_at', nullable: true, default: null })
  updatedAt: Date;
  @ManyToMany(() => Users, (users) => users.entitys, {
    onDelete: 'RESTRICT',
    onUpdate: 'CASCADE',
    eager: true,
  })
  users?: Users[];
}
```

I've tried to make like this but still error like this

```
user.entitys = entitys;
user.divisis = divisis;
user.departemens = departemen;
user.createdBy = createdByUser; //this is my experiment
```

and this is the error

**error :
type 'UsersEntity' is not assignable to type 'string'.
user.createdBy = createdByUser;**